# Random line struct from file

Tags: c, file

I have this struct:

```
struct Equipe {
    char NomEquipe[20];
    int Sigle;
    char j1[20];
    char j2[20];
    char j3[20];
    char j4[20];
    char j5[20];
};
```

I have stored some teams on a file with this function

```
int creerFile1(char *fnom) {
    FILE *fp;
    struct Equipe newrecord;


    fp=fopen(fnom,"a+");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Erreur , Fichier Non ouvert!");
        return -1;
    }


    printf("Nom Equipe : \n");
    scanf("%s", newrecord.NomEquipe);
    printf("Sigle Equipe :\n");
    scanf("%d", &newrecord.Sigle);
    printf("Nom Joueur 1 : \n");
    scanf("%s", newrecord.j1);
    printf("Nom Joueur 2 : \n");
    scanf("%s", newrecord.j2);
    printf("Nom Joueur 3 : \n");
    scanf("%s", newrecord.j3);
    printf("Nom Joueur 4 : \n");
    scanf("%s", newrecord.j4);
    printf("Nom Joueur 5 : \n");
    scanf("%s", newrecord.j5);

    fwrite(&newrecord, sizeof(struct Equipe), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And now I want to select random teams 
so I need to pick only random first record of the struct I mean only teamname !

and store those random teams in a file

This is how I read all my struc

```
int lireFile1(char *fnom) {
    FILE *fp;
    struct Equipe myrecord;

    fp=fopen(fnom,"r");
    if (!fp) {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("The following records are in the binary file %s:\n", fnom);
    while (fread(&myrecord,sizeof(struct Equipe),1,fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", myrecord.NomEquipe);
        printf("%c\n", myrecord.Sigle);
        printf("%s\n\n", myrecord.j1);
        printf("%s\n\n", myrecord.j2);
        printf("%s\n\n", myrecord.j3);
        printf("%s\n\n", myrecord.j4);
        printf("%s\n\n", myrecord.j5);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

so the question is, how can I select those random teams from the first file, and store them into a new file?

Comment: How to select those random teams ! and store them into a new file

Comment: The [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) function doesn't return a pointer, so comparison with `NULL` is pointless.

Comment: Regarding your question, you already know how to write the structure, so your only problem would be to randomly select the structure you want to write to the new file, right?

Comment: randomly select some structures , and save only the first input of each randomely selected structures into a new file

Comment: Read about the [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) function, as well as the [`fputs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) and [`fprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) functions.

Comment: I did @JoachimPileborg , that's why I'm having this issue and I asked some advice

Comment: Read all the values from file, store in array of structure, then you can use `rand()` to get a random number, fetch that random number record from array of structure.

Comment: Read the linked references, they all have some example code.